# NServiceBus events lost when published in separate thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nservicebus

I've been working on getting long running messages working with NServiceBus on an Azure transport.  Based off [this document](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/azure-service-bus-long-running/?version=asb_8), I thought I could get away with firing off the long process in a separate thread, marking the event handler task as complete and then listening for custom OperationStarted or OperationComplete events.  I noticed the OperationComplete event is not received by my handlers most cases.  In fact, the only time it is received is when I publish it immediately after the OperationStarted event is published.  Any actual processing in between somehow prevents the completion event from being received.  Here is my code:

**Abstract class used for long running messages**

```
public abstract class LongRunningOperationHandler<TMessage> : IHandleMessages<TMessage> where TMessage : class
{
    protected ILog _logger => LogManager.GetLogger<LongRunningOperationHandler<TMessage>>();

    public Task Handle(TMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var opStarted = new OperationStarted
        {
            OperationID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            OperationType = typeof(TMessage).FullName
        };
        var errors = new List<string>();
        // Fire off the long running task in a separate thread
        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    _logger.Info($"Operation Started: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(opStarted)}");
                    context.Publish(opStarted);
                    ProcessMessage(message, context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errors.Add(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    var opComplete = new OperationComplete
                    {
                        OperationType = typeof(TMessage).FullName,
                        OperationID = opStarted.OperationID,
                        Errors = errors
                    };

                    context.Publish(opComplete);

                    _logger.Info($"Operation Complete: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(opComplete)}");
                }
            });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected abstract void ProcessMessage(TMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context);
}
```

**Test Implementation**

```
public class TestLongRunningOpHandler : LongRunningOperationHandler<TestCommand>
{
    protected override void ProcessMessage(TestCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // If I remove this, or lessen it to something like 200 milliseconds, the 
        // OperationComplete event gets handled
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Operation Events**

```
public sealed class OperationComplete : IEvent
{
    public Guid OperationID { get; set; }
    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    public bool Success => !Errors?.Any() ?? true;
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public DateTimeOffset CompletedOn { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}

public sealed class OperationStarted : IEvent
{
    public Guid OperationID { get; set; }
    public string OperationType { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartedOn { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

**Handlers**

```
public class OperationHandler : IHandleMessages<OperationStarted>
, IHandleMessages<OperationComplete>
{
    static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger<OperationHandler>();

    public Task Handle(OperationStarted message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        return PrintJsonMessage(message);
    }

    public Task Handle(OperationComplete message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        // This is not hit if ProcessMessage takes too long
        return PrintJsonMessage(message);
    }

    private Task PrintJsonMessage<T>(T message) where T : class
    {
        var msgObj = new
        {
            Message = typeof(T).Name,
            Data = message
        };
        logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgObj, Formatting.Indented));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

I'm certain that the `context.Publish()` calls are being hit because the `_logger.Info()` calls are printing messages to my test console.  I've also verified they are hit with breakpoints.  In my testing, anything that runs longer than 500 milliseconds prevents the handling of the OperationComplete event.

If anyone can offer suggestions as to why the OperationComplete event is not hitting the handler when any significant amount of time has passed in the ProcessMessage implementation, I'd be extremely grateful to hear them.  Thanks!

**-- Update --**
In case anyone else runs into this and is curious about what I ended up doing:

After [an exchange](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/5121) with the developers of NServiceBus, I decided on using a watchdog saga that implemented the IHandleTimeouts interface to periodically check for job completion.  I was using saga data, updated when the job was finished, to determine whether to fire off the `OperationComplete` event in the timeout handler.  This presented an other issue: when using In-Memory Persistence, the saga data was [not persisted](https://docs.particular.net/persistence/in-memory) across threads even when it was locked by each thread.  To get around this, I created an interface specifically for long running, in-memory data persistence.  This interface was injected into the saga as a singleton, and thus used to read/write saga data across threads for long running operations.

I know that In-Memory Persistence is not recommended, but for my needs configuring another type of persistence (like Azure tables) was overkill; I simply want the `OperationComplete` event to fire under normal circumstances.  If a reboot happens during a running job, I don't need to persist the saga data. The job will be cut short anyway and the saga timeout will handle firing the `OperationComplete` event with an error if the job runs longer than a set maximum time.

Comment: This question has also been answered by the developers on the official NServiceBus GitHub repository here: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/5121

Comment: Thanks, @Sabacc, I updated my answer to link to the issue I opened with NServiceBus and to explain what my end solution was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is that if `ProcessMessage` is fast enough, you might get the current `context` before it gets invalidated, such as being disposed.

By returning from `Handle` successfully, you're telling NServiceBus: "I'm done with this message", so it may do what it wants with the `context` as well, such as invalidating it.  In the background processor, you need an endpoint instance, not a message context.

By the time the new task starts running, you don't know if `Handle` has returned or not, so you should just consider the message has already been consumed and is thus unrecoverable.  If errors happen in your separate task, you can't retry them.

Avoid long running processes without persistence.  The sample you mention has a server that stores a work item from a message, and a process that polls this storage for work items.  Perhaps not ideal, in case you scale out processors, but it won't lose messages.

To avoid constant polling, merge the server and the processor, poll inconditionally once when it starts, and in `Handle` schedule a polling task.  Take care for this task to only poll if no other polling task is running, otherwise it may become worse than constant polling.  You may use a semaphore to control this.

To scale out, you must have more servers.  You need to measure if the cost of N processors polling is greater than sending to N servers in a round-robin fashion, for some N, to know which approach actually performs better.  In practice, polling is good enough for a low N.

Modifying the sample for multiple processors may require less deployment and configuration effort, you just add or take processors, while adding or removing servers needs changing their enpoints in all places (e.g. config files) that point to them.

Another approach would be to break the long process into steps.  NServiceBus has  sagas.  It's an approach usually implemented for a know or bounded amount of steps.  For an unknown amount of steps, it's still feasible, although some might consider it an abuse of the seemingly intended purpose of sagas.

Comment: Thanks, @acelent.  I ended up using a watchdog saga as suggested by the NServiceBus developers, but your answer addresses why the context was becoming invalidated.